# How to store prompt() value in to the Database in php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

we have a program that has two button(approve and disapprove). Our problem is when i hit on the button, the value on the prompt doesn't save on the database.

**ServiceRequest.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['user']) || !isset($_SESSION['lname']) || !isset($_SESSION['fname']) || !isset($_SESSION['lname']) || !isset($_SESSION['pass']) || !isset($_SESSION['assign']) || !isset($_SESSION['department']) || !isset($_SESSION['branch']) || !isset($_SESSION['province']) || !isset($_SESSION['position']))
{
    header('Location:login.php');
}
include 'config.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="image/fblogo.ico">
    <title>FB | ITS&CMS</title>
    <link href="dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- <link href="signin.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dist/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"></script>">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/body.css">
    <script src="assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
    <script src="dist/js/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="dist/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
          $('#otable').DataTable({
            "searching": false,
            "order" : [[ 5, "desc" ]]
          });

        $("#search").click(function(){
            $("#searchPanelWrap").slideToggle("slow");
        });
        $("#searchServiceRequests").click(function(){
            var filterVal ="";

            filterVal = "srfno=" + $('#srf').val() + "&branch=" + $('#branch').val() + "&dept=" + $('#dept').val() + "&reqf=" + $('#datereqfrom').val() + "&reqt=" + $('#datereqto').val() + "";
            document.location.href = 'servicereq.php?s=1&' + filterVal;
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <?php
        include "header.php";
      ?>
    </nav>
    <br><br><br><br><br>
    <div class="form">
      <center>
        <fieldset id="fieldsetform">
          <div class="form"><br><br>
            <center><h4>Service Request Forms</h4></center>
            <ul class="tab-group"><br>
              <a href="servicereq.php?s=0"><button style="width: 150px; height: 50px;" type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="Service">Service Request</button></a>
              <a href="appreq.php"><button style="width: 150px; height: 50px;" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Service">Close Request</button></a>
              <button class="btn" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;" value="Search" id="search"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter"></span></btn>
            </ul>
            <div id="searchPanelWrap" style="padding-bottom:10px; display:none;">
                <input style = "text" placeholder = "SRF No." id="srf"/>
                <input style = "text" placeholder = "Branch" id="branch"/>
                <input style = "text" placeholder = "Department" id="dept"/>
                Request Date From: <input style = "text" type = "date" value="" id="datereqfrom"/>
                Request Date To: <input style = "text" type = "date" value="" id="datereqto"/>
                <button class="btn btn-default" id="searchServiceRequests">Search</button>
            </div>
            <form action="downloadfile.php" method="get"></form>
            <?php
                  //if(!$uname == 'uname' && !$pass = 'pass'){
              include 'dbconn.php';
                if($_SESSION['assign']!="Main Approver"){
                   $clause = "dept = '".$_SESSION['department']."' AND city='".$_SESSION['branch']."' AND type != '".$_SESSION['assign']."' AND status = 'PENDING' ";
                }else{
                   $clause = "status = 'PENDING' ";
                }

                if($_GET["s"] == "1"){  
                $srf = $_GET["srfno"];
                $branch = $_GET["branch"];
                $dept = $_GET["dept"];
                $datereqfrom = $_GET["reqf"];
                $datereqto = $_GET["reqt"];

                $srfFilter = "";
                $brFilter = "";
                $deptFilter = "";
                $reqFilter = "";

                if($srf != ""){
                    $srfFilter = "AND SRFNo = '".$srf."' ";
                }
                if($branch != ""){
                    $brFilter = "AND city = '".$branch."' ";
                }
                if($dept != ""){
                    $deptFilter = "AND dept = '".$dept."' ";
                }
                if($datereqfrom != "" && $datereqto != ""){
                    $reqFilter = "AND RequestDateTime BETWEEN '".$datereqfrom." 00:00:00.000' AND '".$datereqto." 23:59:59.999' ";
                }
                $addFilter = $srfFilter.$brFilter.$deptFilter.$reqFilter;

                }else{
                    $addFilter = "";
                }

              $record= getAllServicePending($clause.$addFilter);
              echo '<table id="otable" class="table table-striped">';
              echo '<thead>';
              echo '<th>SRF No.</th>';
              echo '<th>Last Name</th>';
              echo '<th>First Name</th>';
              echo '<th>Branch</th>';
              echo '<th>Department</th>';
              echo '<th>Date Requested</th>';
              echo '<th>Attached File</th>';
              echo '<th>Service Form View</th>';
              echo '<th>Status</th>';
              echo '<th>Action</th>';

              echo '</thead>';
              echo "<tbody>";

              foreach($record as $r){
                $i=0;
                echo '<tr>';
                $idno;
                foreach($r as $fields){
                  if($i==0) $idno=$fields;
                  //echo '<td>'.strtoupper($fields).'</td>';
                  $i++;
                }

                $files = $r['file'];
                echo '<td>'.$r['SRFNo'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$r['lastreq'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$r['firstreq'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$r['city'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$r['dept'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$r['RequestDateTime'].'</td>';
                echo '<td><a href="dlserv.php?filename='.$files.'">'.$r['file'].'</a></td>';
                echo '<td><a href="serviceform.php?idno='.$idno.'">Service Request</a></td>';
                echo '<td>'.$r['status'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="window.location.href=`approveserv.php?idno='.$idno.'&status=approve`" style="width:136px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" style="padding-right:5px"></span>APPROVE</button><br>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="window.location.href=`approveserv.php?idno='.$idno.'&status=disapprove`" style="width:136px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down" style="padding-right:5px"></span>DISAPPROVE</button>
                 </td>';

                echo '</tr>';
              }
              echo "</tbody>";
              echo '</table>';
                  //}
         ?><br><br>
         </div>
        </fieldset>
      </center>
    </div><?php
      include "footer.php";
    ?> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is how I used the prompt(), this will just perform the SQL for approve and disapporve but the value of the prompt does not store to the database.

### SQL query:

```
 approveserv.php<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['user']) || !isset($_SESSION['lname']) || !isset($_SESSION['fname']) || !isset($_SESSION['lname']) || !isset($_SESSION['pass']) || !isset($_SESSION['assign']) || !isset($_SESSION['department']) || !isset($_SESSION['branch']) || !isset($_SESSION['province']) || !isset($_SESSION['position']))
{
    header('Location:login.php');
}
include ('dbconn.php');

$idno = $_GET["idno"];
$reqstat = $_GET["status"];
$s = ret_status_service($idno);
$user = $_SESSION['user'];
$db = site_db();

    if($reqstat=="approve"){
    $sql = "UPDATE services SET status ='APPROVED', ApprovalDateTime = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), ApprovedBy = '".$user."'  WHERE ser_id = ?";
    }else{
    $sql = "UPDATE services SET status ='DISAPPROVED', ApprovalDateTime = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), ApprovedBy = '".$user."'  WHERE ser_id = ?";
    }
$s = $db->prepare($sql);
$s->execute(array($idno));
$db = null;
echo "<script>if(prompt('Successfully ${reqstat}d request.')){document.location.href='servicereq.php?s=0'};</script>";
//    header('location:servicereq.php');
?>
```

Comment: Too much. Break it up. **ie: the `prompt` is irrelevant once the data is "given to PHP"**

Comment: Hello sir, for my case i want to prompt the box when the button is click and input on the text space on why it is disapprove that will also store on to the database . Thank you

Comment: You didn't post the code to get the text from the prompt and store it into the database. Have you already done that?

Comment: Hello Phil, i am confused and no idea on that part since its my first time using this prompt(). on how to get the value and where should I place it.  Thank you for your reply.

Comment: $idno is being output and set oddly.  can you verify that the url is correct and $idno is indeed being passed in as expected?

Answer (score 0):

If your concerns are how to get the input of prompt dialog and send it to `servicereq.php`. You could refer to the following code:

```
//servicereq.php - to get the prompt message from approveserv.php and store it to database
if(isset($_REQUEST['prompt_msg'])){
  $prompt_msg= $_REQUEST['prompt_msg'];
  // you could continue to store it in the database
}

//approveserv.php -  to output the javascript and get the prompt message and send it to servicereq.php
echo "<script>if(prompt_msg=prompt('Successfully ".$reqstat."d action request.')){document.location.href='servicereq.php?prompt_msg='+prompt_msg+'&s=0'};</script>";
```

Note: I suppose you could manage to store the prompt msg to the database, so I didn't write the code here.

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_prompt.asp) is a further material for how to use prompt.